# Built local glibc, broke system, how do I ssh without parsing the .bashrc?

Tags: ssh, cluster, bashrc, glibc

The cluster I am on had really old build tools and I needed to use CUDA5. I'm a pretty clever dude and I planned on building the necissary tools.

So, I built a local copy of gcc, bintools, and glibc. Everything a CUDA5 could want. All builds finished without error. and I tested gcc and bintools. Everything was wonderful and I built and ran a few of the programs.

I set up the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`s in the `.bashrc` and logged back in, expecting a productive night ahead.

To my horror I realized that *everything* is dynamically linked.

---

Now I can't do simple commands like `ls`

> [ex@uid377 ~]$ ls ls: error while loading shared libraries:
>   __vdso_time: invalid mode for dlopen(): Invalid argument

and I can't do commands to fix the problem like `rm` or `vim`!

---

Is there a way for me to ssh but also to ignore `.bashrc` file? Any suggestions are much appreciated. This machine is obviously under maintained and I don't know when I could have administrator support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, I found a command that will work

`[ex@uid377 ~]$ echo 'help!' >& .bashrc`

This overwrote the `.bashrc` and I was able to log back in.

---

In retrospect doing `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=''` would also fix this problem.